# How can I remove the harshness from my first music track?

Tags: audacity

I'm using audacity but can't really get it to improve beyond that. It sounds good on some systems but not on most.

Comment: I see I got a thumbs down on my question. I am really sorry I can't be more specific. I just figured one person out of a million would be able to give me a pro tip.

Comment: I think the down vote is for being a "primarily opinion based" question. The track sounds fine to me, other may disagree for who knows what reason.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for the input. I do realize stack exchange is a very intellectual site and questions need to be focused. I will definitely do a lot of research first before posting my next question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the reference track has been taken down, leaving no question at all.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend a lot on the speakers you have.

Listening on my small desktop computer speakers, there's too much bass and treble and not enough mid-range.  Playing with the equaliser to boost the mid-range and cut the bass and treble brought out the vocals, and made the music less harsh overall.

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I am new to frequencies, so i did not know which to cut. i will try and make some of these changes, thanks alot.